# PHP Socket and TCP IP Command

Tags: php, asp.net, vb.net

I have a device with relays connected to my network. I am able to connect to device via the built in url host to turn on and off the relays. What I would like to do is be able to send commands to the device turning on and off the relays either via php, vb code or make my own ASP url's for each relay that will do that same thing. I am using Visual Studio 2013.

I have the IP of the device and the port number. 
I need to send it a 6 byte command: example 
0xFD,Ox2,020,1,0,0x5d
This command will tell Relay 1 to turn on.
0xFD,Ox2,020,1,1,0x5d
This command will tell Relay 1 to turn off.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated Thank you!

Comment: if you can control it via url (so presumably, http?), why can't you just do `file_get_contents('http://address.of.device/params/to/control/relay')`?

Comment: Yes it is via http. When I was looking for code I came a cross something like that. I am still pretty new to web side of programming so was unsure how to put the code together.

Comment: Do you have any security concerns or are these all internal network addresses?

Comment: It will be all internal network address. I work at a company and my boss wanted me to try and get this device working so we can use it on the production line. He wants me to make an ASP website that we can use to turn on and off these relays from inside the building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of building an ASP web site just to turn on/off the device, you can simply create a very simple HTML page with 2 buttons (ON and OFF). If you put this page on the network, it can be opened by any browser.

Assuming that your command string is processed as an URL, the Javascript functions executed when clicking on a button would call the following procedure:

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

If the device is controlled by TCP/IP, you may need to code some C# functions, unless using a utility allowing to send data to TCP/IP (example "Packet sender").

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to check out [fsockopen](http://php.net/fsockopen)

You can do something like:

```
$socket = fsockopen($ip, $port);
if($socket) {
  fwrite($socket, $string);
}
```